# How can I see the engine log when solving a LP using pulp (python)?

Tags: linear-programming, python, pulp

I wonder which command should I use to see how the steps the pulp solver is doing when solving a linear program.

Comment: If you check the pulp documentation [here](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/pulp.html), you see that the solver has a `msg` argument that if passed as `True`, will print the log.

Comment: prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))